# Is there such a thing as a truly objective, neutral, factual news source for world news?

Tags: news

I'm trying to fetch not headlines but rather facts. I have no interest in reading any "opinions" or "articles".

I do not want to hear propaganda such as `Thousands Fleeing Ukraine After Russia Attack`, but instead `Russia fires 10-12 missiles toward Ukraine` with a timestamp attached to it, etc.

I hope I make myself clear. I've stopped reading any so-called "mainstream" since many years, but even the so-called "alternative" news are full of idiotic, unwanted "opinions" which I have no interest in wading through.

I've already gone through the phase of collecting "all sources", but it very quickly exhausts me. I don't want to manually scan through tons of "opinion" headlines. I just want cold, established facts with zero "feelings" or "spins" added. Just a feed of "events that happen". I imagine it to look something like this (these are completely made up "facts"):

```
Microsoft releases Windows 12
YouTube removes downvotes
Ukraine adopts Bitcoin as primary currency
Russia buys 10-15 containers of Bitcoin miners
USA elects John Doe as new president
Nintendo stops making hardware
```

And so on.

I have never been able to find any such thing anywhere. It always ends up with me having to add a million different keyword-based filters and then unwanted "opinions" still keep slipping through. Slashdot is a perfect example of something where 1% is actual news but 99% of it is propaganda/noise. It drives me insane to try to wade through headlines even with all my "automatic processing".

Is there really no such project run where they only report "what happened" rather than "how I am supposed to feel and think about it; here is my annoying and wrong opinion which I'm forcing down your throat"?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there exists objective neutral facts for notable news.

Hypothetically, you could create a news feed that takes in all of the stock market buys and sells. Then you could generate a news story every hour about the changes. So you would have an objective neutral fact about each company every hour. But what is the value in that? Someone needs to determine if any news story is notable enough to publish or read. At the very point that someone desides to publish or not publish a sentence, paragraph or article, you no longer have an objective fact. It has been subjected to a criteria of either noteable or not. One person will find an article about a stock notable if they have an investment in to that company. But another person might make a different judgement call. Publishing bias is just one of the many issues that make it impossible to find the facts that you are looking for.
There are many other issues, including that different people are going to have different facts about the same event just because they have a different point of view. A great example of this is a 2008 movie, Vantage point, that depicts witnesses with different points of view.

The truth about the human condition comes from listening to all sides of the story, but that takes a lot of work so most people don't even try.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a source of news that gets close to what you are wanting:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events